# Whi i get the error "token must be a string"?

Tags: reactjs, token

I'm trying to use useEffect to set the behaviour for my room and at first, i wanna use the **token** and **roomName** to connect to the Twilio Video service. However, i got the error as "**token must be a string**" in my **Room.js**. I don't know what's wrong? can anyone help me?

VideoChat.js:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Lobby from "./Lobby";
import Room from "./Room"
function VideoChat() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [roomName, setRoomName] = useState("");
  const [token, setToken] = useState(null);

  const handleUsernameChange = useCallback((event) => {
    setUsername(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  const handleRoomNameChange = useCallback((event) => {
    setRoomName(event.target.value);
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = useCallback(
    async (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      const data = await fetch("/video/token", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
          identity: username,
          room: roomName,
        }),
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }).then((res) => res.json());
      setToken(data.token);
    },
    [username, roomName]
  );

  const handleLogout = useCallback((event) => {
    setToken(null);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      if (token){" "}
      {
        <div>
          <Room roomName={roomName} token={token} handleLogout={handleLogout} />
        </div>
      }{" "}
      else{" "}
      {
        <Lobby
          username={username}
          roomName={roomName}
          handleUsernameChange={handleUsernameChange}
          handleRoomNameChange={handleRoomNameChange}
          handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        />
      }{" "}
    </div>
  );
}
export default VideoChat;
```

Lobby.js:

```
import React from "react";
    
    const Lobby = ({
      username,
      handleUsernameChange,
      roomName,
      handleRoomNameChange,
      handleSubmit
    }) => {
      return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <h2> Enter a room </h2>{" "}
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="name"> Name: </label>{" "}
            <input
              type="text"
              id="field"
              value={username}
              onChange={handleUsernameChange}
              required
            />
          </div>{" "}
          <div>
            <label htmlFor="room"> Room name: </label>{" "}
            <input
              type="text"
              id="room"
              value={roomName}
              onChange={handleRoomNameChange}
              required
            />
          </div>{" "}
          <button type="submit"> Submit </button>{" "}
        </form>
      );
    };
    
    export default Lobby;
```

Room.js:

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import Video from "twilio-video";
    
    const Room = ({ roomName, token, handleLogout }) => {
      const [room, setRoom] = useState(null);
      const [participants, setParticipants] = useState([]);
    
      const remoteParticipants = participants.map(participant=> {
        <p key={participant.sid}>{participant.identity}</p>
      })
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const participantConnected = participant => {
          setParticipants(prevParticipants => [...prevParticipants, participant]);
        };
        const participantDisconnected = participant => {
          setParticipants(prevParticipants =>
            prevParticipants.filter(p => p !== participant)
          );
        };
        Video.connect(token, {
          name: roomName
        }).then(room => {
          setRoom(room);
          room.on('participantConnected', participantConnected);
          room.on('participantDisconnected', participantDisconnected);
          room.participants.forEach(participantConnected);
        });
      });
    
      return (
        <div className="room">
          <h2>Room: {roomName}</h2>
          <button onClick={handleLogout}>Log out</button>
          <div className="local-participant">
            {room ? (<p key={room.localParticipant.sid}>{room.localParticipant.identity}</p>) : ''}
          </div>
          <h3>Remote Participants</h3>
          <p>{remoteParticipants}</p>
        </div>
      )
    };
    
    export default Room;
```

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-bhaskara-oo12s?file=/src/Lobby.js

Comment: You can't write standard JS if statements within the returned JSX. In VideoChat.js, you attempt to conditionally render Room based on if a token is there, but that doesn't actually work, so you are actually rendering Room with an empty/null token. To conditionally render, you can use something like this: `token ? <Room ... /> : <Lobby ... />`

Comment: i made it ike this but my room doesn't render either...: https://codesandbox.io/s/video-chat-y67nv?file=/src/VideoChat.js